# Make Accessory indicator clickable

Tags: ios, uitableview, accessory

I am showing a custom accessory view within my uitableview using the code below. Is it possible to target the accessory image as clickable? Do I need to make it a action? I need to make only the image clickable as within `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`I am producing a alert for another function.

```
cell.accessoryView = [[ UIImageView alloc ]
                          initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"acc_icon.png"]];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the accessory view a button or keep the image view and add a gesture recognizer (be sure to enable user interaction).

---

Instead of

```
[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage...
```

Use

```
[UIButton buttonWithType...
```

And configure the button target, action, image / text.

Comment: how would I change it to a button?